# How can I get revoked flag for current task in Celery worker?

Tags: python, celery

I want to implement task cancellation with cleanup process on Celery + RabbitMQ broker.
How can I get "REVOKED" status of current task in Celery worker?

```
# tasks.py -- celery worker
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
  for i in range(0, 10):
    time.sleep(1)
    # I want check here for cleanup.
  return x + y

# caller.py
from tasks import add
result = add.delay(4, 4)
result.revoke()
```

Celery supports [Abortable tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.abortable.html), but it only works the database backend.

Python 3.4.1 / Celery 3.1.17 / RabbitMQ 3.4.4

Answer (score 0):

[Felippe Da Motta Raposo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1691166/felippe-da-motta-raposo)'s suggestion works inside my custom task:

```
from celery import Task
from celery.task.control import inspect

WORKER_NAME = "celery@server"
inspector = inspect([WORKER_NAME])

class CustomTask(Task):
    def _is_revoked(self):
        revoked_list = inspector.revoked()
        return (revoked_list and self.task_id in revoked_list[WORKER_ADDRESS]

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.task_id = self.request.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [scheduled_tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html#celery.app.control.Inspect.registered_tasks), you can ask celery if your task is scheduled to run.

EX.:

```
    import celery
    celery_inspect = celery.current_app.control.inspect()
    celery_inspect.registered_tasks()
```

This method returns a dict with all celery scheduled tasks by worker.

Comment: so, what should I do revoke that task?

Comment: If you want to revoke the task just do this: 
`from celery.task import control`
`control.revoke({celery_task_id})`

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know "Have I (=task) been revoked by Celery framework?", not "revoke some specific task".

Comment: I never tried this but I think it works: ```import celery
    celery_inspect = celery.current_app.control.inspect()``` ```celery_inspect.revoked()```. It should return a list with all revoked tasks.